# Python: Type hint for any class which is iterable with fixed number of elements

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

**TLDR**:

I have a function that has an argument which can be any object that can be iterated on and return two *ints*, such as *Tuple[int, int]* or *List[int, int]*. More so, any custom class which has *__getitem__()* or *__iter__()* methods that allow accessing and unpacking two *ints* should also work, such that:

```
from custom_class import CustomClass


c = CustomClass() 
# c[0] = 10
# c[1] = 20
# c[i] -> Error , for i != 0,1


def my_func(item: ?) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    i, j = item
    # ...
    return tuple(i, j)
```

Which should be the type hint used for the item argument in this case? Should I just use *Iterable* or is there a way to specify that the argument should be an iterable of two *ints*? Would an abstract base class work?

---

**Long version:**

I'm currently developing a raster-based simulation. Since many methods in various classes require the raster coordinates of a cell, I decided to create a simple dataclass to represent the coordinates and provide simple functionality:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class CellIndex:
    i: int
    j: int

    def __getitem__(self, item: int) -> int:
        return astuple(self)[item]

    def __add__(self, other: CellIndex) -> CellIndex:
        if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
            return CellIndex(self.i + other.i, self.j + other.j)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __sub__(self, other: CellIndex) -> CellIndex:
        if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
            return CellIndex(self.i - other.i, self.j - other.j)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 2
```

I am now creating another class which is basically a wrapper for xarray.DataArray:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(data: xarray.DataArray) -> None:
        self._data = data

    # ...

    # GridCell is a dataclass
    def item(self, coords: ?) -> GridCell:
        i, j = coords
        cell_data = self._data.item(i, j)
        # Do processing here
        return GridCell(cell_data)
```

For this specific class, I don't require any of the additional functionality provided by the *CellIndex* class. As such, I'd like the *coords* argument in  Grid.item() to be any object which can be iterated on and return two *int*, such as *Tuple[int, int]*, *List[int, int]* or *CellIndex*, corresponding to the coordinates of a cell. My question is: which type hint should I use for the *coords* argument?

I could create a TypeVar with these three types, but that would lead to a deep coupling with *CellIndex* and not allow for further generalization in the future without manually modifying the created TypeVar. I was thinking of creating an abstract base class, but I'm not quite sure if this is a viable option or how to actually implement it in this case.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `@dataclass(frozen=True)` vs. inheriting from `typing.NamedTuple`? The latter does "waste" 4-8 bytes per instance (because each stores its length, even though the length is fixed for all instances), but `dataclass` wastes more unless you explicitly define `__slots__ = 'i', 'j'` or, on 3.10 and later only, pass `slots=True` to the `dataclass` decorator to make it generate the `__slots__` for you. Granted, that won't support *every* iterable of length two containing `int`s, but it would make `CellIndex` work with little effort (saves defining two special methods too).

Comment: @ShadowRanger No particular reason actually. At any given time I only have a few instances of CellIndex, so no worries about memory usage there. Nevertheless, I was planning on adding slots, but it wasn't a priority and it must have slipped my mind. Anyway, I might go with your suggestion and switch to inheriting NamedTuple. Thanks!

Comment: Size is not an attribute of iterable values. (A type that *supports* the iterator protocol may have a specific size, but it's not part of the iterator protocol itself.)

Comment: Please note that `List[int, int]` you mentioned is invalid annotation and won't typecheck. For your use case I would suggest `tuple[int, int]` as annotation. To make `CellIndex` compatible you can use NamedTuple (explained in comments above) or stick with dataclass (there's nothing wrong with it!) with little magic (`if TYPE_CHECKING: base = tuple[int, int]; else: base = object` and then `class CellIndex(base): ...`). It's special case when `mypy` does support "dynamic" base.